# ANDROID - hide an android app from the Play Store

Tags: android, google-play

it is possible to make a android app unavailable from searches on the play store. the users that are allowed to download the apps will have a url pointing to it. is it possible?

Comment: You mean like a closed beta ?

Comment: I believe this is only the case if you have a business account, then you can open your app only to users authorised to download it. I could be wrong, but I don't think google supports selective apps for the masses as yet.

Comment: No. Develop your own enterprise server. Play doesn't do it

Comment: @2Dee yes a closed beta will do the trick. what do i need to do that?

Comment: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en